# Filesystem Mini-Filter driver project template doesn't exist in Visual Studio 2019/2022

Tags: filesystems, minifilter

So, I wanted to develop a little Filesystem Mini-Filter driver for windows.
I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 community edition with the following list of packages:

```
WDK
SDK
Python Development
Desktop development with C++
Universal Windows Platform development
Linux and embedded development with C++
```

Optional Packages:

```
C++ CMake tools for Linux
IntelliCode
Embedded and IoT tools
Legacy Embedded and IoT tools
```

With those installed I still don't have `FileSystem Mini-Filter` project type available. I also tried to search for it under Individual Components but it do not exist.

I came across this question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/720582/filesystem-mini-filter-template-won39t-appear-in-v.html
Which seem to have worked for the guy, but a re-install did not work for me.

Is there anything I am missing here?